# Problem 8 Section 4.13 Kreyszig Functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, closed-graph

I am self studying Functional analysis from Kreyszig and I am thinking about this exercise which is a part of section Closed Graph theoram.

> **Problem:** let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces and let $T: X \to Y$ be a closed linear operator.
>
> 1. Show that image $A$ of a compact subset $C$ of $X$ is closed in $Y$.
> 2. Show that inverse image $B$ of a compact set $K$ which is subset of $Y$ is closed in $X$.

My attempt: for 1. $A$ is compact implies $A$ is closed. $T$ is closed but $Y$ is not Banach.  I have to show that if $f(c_i ) \to f(c)$ then it is closed in $X$.  But I have no idea on how to proceed

Can someone please give some hints?

Comment: @David Mitra Did you deleted your comment?

Comment: Yes, was too much detail. But in both parts, all you need are the definitions and the fact that your compact sets are sequentially compact. For 1, start by choosing a   sequence, $(a_n)$, in $A$  with $a_n\rightarrow a\in Y$. You need to show   $a\in A$. To do this, pick $c_n$ in $C$ with Tc_n=a_n$. ... (Rest for you.)

Answer (score 3):

Let $(c_n) \subset C$ and and $T(c_n) \to y$. We have to show that $y \in A$.  Since $C$ is compact there is a subsequence $(c_{n_k})$ converging to some $c \in C$. Since $(c_{n_k},T(c_{n_k})) $ is  a sequence in the graph of $T$ converging to $(c,y)$ it follows this limit belongs to the graph, so $y=Tc \in A$.

Let $(x_n)$ be sequence in $T^{-1}(B)$ converging to some $x$. We have to show that $x \in T^{-1}(B)$. Now $T(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence  $T(x_{n_k})$ in $B$. Let $T(x_{n_k}) \to y \in B$. Then $(x_{n_k},T(x_{n_k})) \to (x,y)$. Hence $(x,y)$ belongs to the graph, and $y=Tx$. But then $x \in T^{-1}(B)$ because $y \in B$.